# connect to socket.IO from native android

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am developing a chat for service for my application and have been trying to connect to socket.io from my native android application. I am using :-

- https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java
- https://github.com/nkzawa/engine.io-client.java
- https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

my activity class looks like

```
private Socket socket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    try {
        socket = IO.socket("http://ridewithme.in:49154/socket");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    send.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

        text = message.getText().toString();
        socket.connect();
        socket.send(text);
        socket.disconnect();
    }
}
```

but i keep on getting XHR polling error (logs from the Socket.emit())

```
com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.SocketIOException: Connection error
```

My server uses socket.io v1.0.X and it seems to be working fine from a browser. What is possibly going wrong here? Is it an acces origin problem?

Comment: Have you added Internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes… android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: Try replacing socket.connect socket.send and socket.disconnect methods, for this socket.emit("text", text) in case you are expecting a "text" event on the server side.